# Ember Validations and Ember Easyform do not validate the form on submit

Tags: ember.js

As I currently have it set up, my validations are not being shown on the submit on an ember easyForm form. the current setup for the mixin only allows for validations to be shown on focusOut of an input. Does anybody have a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

easyForm is calling validate in the context.

```
Ember.EasyForm.Form = Ember.EasyForm.BaseView.extend({
  // rest of the code removed for brevity
  submit: function(event) {
    var _this = this, promise;

    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    if (Ember.isNone(this.get('context.validate'))) {
      this.get('controller').send(this.action);
    } else {
      if (!Ember.isNone(this.get('context').validate)) {
        promise = this.get('context').validate();
      } else {
        promise = this.get('context.content').validate();
      }
      promise.then(function() {
        if (_this.get('context.isValid')) {
          _this.get('controller').send(_this.action);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Could you verify it's calling your model's validate method? If that's not the case could you raise a bug on easyForm if this isn't the case?

It seems to be that isn't calling validate in the content since it will call the controller  if context.validate `isNone`